# Porque Objecto de classe é null?

Tags: c#

Não percebo porque mas o objecto player é null , nao o estou a chamar bem ?

```
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 localScale;
    public Transform HealthTransform;
    public Player PlayerObj;

    void Start () {

        localScale = HealthTransform.localScale;
        PlayerObj = new Player(); 
    }

    void Update () {



        if(PlayerObj.GetPlayerAxis().Equals("P1Horizontal"))
        {
            localScale.x = Player.HealthAmountP1;
            if (gameObject.name.Equals("P1Health"))
            {
                HealthTransform.localScale = localScale;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerObj.GetPlayerAxis().Equals("P2Horizontal"))
        {
            localScale.x = Player.HealthAmountP2;

            if(gameObject.name.Equals("P2Health"))
            {
                HealthTransform.localScale = localScale;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Se você executar Update antes do Start com certeza vai estar null.

Comment: E o gameObject, você instancia aonde?

Answer (score 1):

O objeto `Player` é inicializado apenas no método `Start` o que significa que você deve chamar o método `Start` no seu código antes de qualquer chamada do método `Update`. Uma solução para evitar isso seria acrescentar um construtor à sua classe inicializando a variável `Player`.

```
public HealthBar ()
{
    localScale = HealthTransform.localScale;
    PlayerObj = new Player();
}
```